# How to separate a list into two lists?

Tags: java

[here is a big list ,I want to separate this list into two lists according to "A7750" and "A7741"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vli8N.png)  
I also try to write codes to implement it but it failed

```
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A7750 0.0 28.30");
    list.add("A7750 0.3 28.30");
    list.add("A7741 0.0 31.40");
    list.add("A7741 0.1 31.40");
    Boolean tag=true;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        if(i>=1){
        String str[]=list.get(i).split("\t");  
        String str1[]=list.get(i-1).split("\t");
        if(tag){
            list1.add(list.get(i-1));   
            if(!str[0].equals(str1[0])){
                for(String t:list1){
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
                list1.clear();
                System.out.println("...");
            }
            }
        }

        }



     }
}
```

Comment: as a side note, this rather looks like it should be a `List<someClassForTheStringContent>` than a `List<String>`

Comment: I just can get one list instead of two lists,do you have a better method to do it?

Comment: @Ming Please explain what you want the end result to be. If there are 1000 rows in `list`, would they all start with either `A7741` or `A7750`? And then you should end up with 2 lists, one with all of the entries starting with `A7741`, and the other with all of them starting with `A77501`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a test class that should do what you want:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> tagMap = new HashMap<>();
        // Populate the list
        list.add("A7750 0.0 28.30");
        list.add("A7750 0.3 28.30");
        list.add("A7741 0.0 31.40");
        list.add("A7741 0.1 31.40");
        list.add("A7752 0.5 31.40");
        list.add("A7752 0.7 31.40");

        // Loop through all the entries
        for (String entry : list) {
            // Split on space to get the tag
            String tag = entry.split(" ")[0];
            // Get the list of data starting with this tag
            List<String> tagList = tagMap.get(tag);
            if (tagList == null) {
                // If there are no other entries for tag yet, add a
                // new list to the map
                tagList = new ArrayList<>();
                tagMap.put(tag, tagList);
            }
            // Add the current entry to the list
            tagList.add(entry);
        }

        // Print out the results
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : tagMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of it, `tagMap` will contain mappings from each tag to the list of entries starting with that tag. In order to get the list of entries for a given tag (such as `A7750`), do this: `tagMap.get("A7750");`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `String.startsWith` to check each string in your list starts with what you want and add to corresponding new list.

```
for(String element: bigList){
    if(element.startsWith("A7750")){
        list1.add(element);
    }
    else if(element.startsWith("A7741")){
        list2.add(element);
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

If you have thousands of rows, you can use a `Map` to store the lists as follows.

```
Map<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap<>();
for(String element: bigList){
    // Split each element by space.
    String parts=element.split(" ");

    // if the map contains your key ex: "A7741", add the string to the corresponding list.
    if(map.containsKey(parts[0])){
        List<String> list = map.get(parts[0]);
        list.add(element);
    }else{
        // create a new list and add it to the map with a new key.
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(element);
        map.put(parts[0],list);
    }
}
```

In the end, the map will have a set of lists where each entry's `key` is the string from which it's elements are staring from.

I have assumed that your strings always has a format similar to `A7750 0.0 28.30`

Comment: Thanks for your codes.But I don't want to define it absolutely like "A7750",you know the the first String in 1 row and the first string in 2 row is the same.I want put this as my condition instead "A7750"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you be more specific? What do you mean by `"you know the the first String in 1 row and the first string in 2 row is the same.I want put this as my condition instead "A7750"`

Comment: if my biglist has more than 4 rows data and have 1000 rows data,if I use the method like that you write "A7750","A7741",I have to write 500 strings like this. It is a hard work. Can you improve your code?

Comment: Update the answer to accommodate your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of things that you could correct.

1. The split must happen on a space character (" ") and not "\t" character.
2. Adding the first element directly to another list and applying checks for the subsequent elements.

Also, I added a new list to the mix for keeping things simple.

You can use this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("A7750 0.0 28.30");
        list.add("A7750 0.3 28.30");
        list.add("A7741 0.0 31.40");
        list.add("A7741 0.1 31.40");
        String str[] = list.get(0).split(" ");
        list1.add(list.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            String str1[] = list.get(i).split(" ");
            boolean tag = str[0].equals(str1[0]);
            if (tag) {
                list1.add(list.get(i));
            } else {
                list2.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I have 100 rows data instead just 4 rows data.How to implement it?

Comment: such as I have the biglist like this  "A7750 0.0 28.30"
"A7750 0.0 28.30"
"A7751 0.0 28.30"
"A7751 0.0 28.30"
"A7752 0.0 28.30"
"A7752 0.0 28.30"
"A7752 0.0 28.30"
"A7752 0.0 28.30"

Comment: This would still work provided you just have two tags like A7750 and A7741.

Comment: yes，if I provide more data like A7759,A7742,A6652,A8809....,how to separate this biglist into many lists?

Comment: @Ming, are they always five characters?

Comment: @Ming please see my edited answer. It will work for any amount of data (for example, if there are 10 tags, it will separate the data into 10 lists)

Comment: Only the first column String of every rows are the same, they will be put into the same list. like{A7750,0.0，28.30 A7750 0.3 28.30 } you see in this list it has the same A7750,so they are put into the same list

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `Map` for to hold tags and thier list. By doing this, you can easily find a list according to the tag. This should work for you:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("A7750 0.0 28.30");
list.add("A7741 0.0 31.40");
list.add("A7760 0.1 31.40");
list.add("A7741 0.1 31.40");
list.add("A7750 0.3 28.30");
list.add("A7750 0.6 28.36");
// add if you want more ...

// Create map for different tags and their list 
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfTagAndList = new HashMap<>();    

// Enter the tags and their list into the map         
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    String tag = s.split(" ")[0];
    List<String> listWithTag = new ArrayList<>();

    if(!mapOfTagAndList.containsKey(tag)) {
        listWithTag.add(s);
        mapOfTagAndList.put(tag, listWithTag);
    }
    else {                
        listWithTag = mapOfTagAndList.get(tag);
        listWithTag.add(s);
        mapOfTagAndList.put(tag, listWithTag);
    }
}        

// Print the tags and their lists       
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mapOfTagAndList.entrySet()) {
    String tag = entry.getKey();
    System.out.println("tag = "+tag);

    List<String> tagList = entry.getValue();        
    System.out.println("list for the tag = "+tagList);            
}
```